# 64 bit integer Makefile of MUMPS

Tags: linux, makefile, mumps

anyone can help me with makefile. I don't know what it means below.

**`we use "int" by default but 64-bit integers can be forced by adding the option -DINTSIZE64 in the OPTC entry of your Makefile.inc) and that all libraries called by MUMPS rely on 64-bit integers (metis, ScaLAPACK, BLACS, BLAS)`**

MUMPS use  we use "int" by default but 64-bit integers can be forced by adding the option -DINTSIZE64 in the OPTC entry of your Makefile.inc) and that all libraries called by MUMPS rely on 64-bit integers (metis, ScaLAPACK, BLACS, BLAS)

[makefile.inc][1]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76h60.png)
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qJBO.png

Comment: It means nothing of consequence unless it's important to you for your MUMPS build to use 64-bit integers instead of (probably) 32-bit integers.  Evidently, the MUMPS developers think that the latter is good enough for many purposes, but suppose that some people will want larger ones, or will need larger ones for compatibility with other libraries.

Comment: @JohnBollinger. Hi, Yeah I just want to use 64 bit integer, but I don't know what it means, what is the OPTC entry in makefile.inc?

Comment: The terminology is a bit unconventional, but look for file `Makefile.inc`. Inside, look for a line that starts with `OPTC =` or maybe `OPTC :=`.  Add the text `-DINTSIZE64` at the end of that line, making sure to separate it from whatever comes before with at least one space character.  At least, that's what the given instructions mean to me, without actually looking at any of the files involved myself.